# fxLayout="row" @angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.1" and angular material2

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

```html
<p class="normal-gray-txt text-center">
  <b>
    Choose reference
    architecture
  </b>
</p>
<form[formGroup=""]="custAppDetail" (ngSubmit=""
fxLayout="column" >
  <div fxLayout = "row" >
    <label fxFlex="1 6 60%"> Architecture file source</label>
    <md-select fxFlex = "3 1 40%" placeholder="abc"
      formControlName="archFileSource" (ngModelChange="")="toNeoGit($event)">
      <md-option* ngFor = "let env of archFileSrc"[value=""] = "env.value" >
        {{ env.viewValue }}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout = "row" >
    <label fxFlex="1 6 60%"> Architecture file</label>
    <md-select fxFlex = "3 1 40%" placeholder= "Choose file" formControlName= "archFile" >    
      <md - option * ngFor = "let env of ar"[value] = "env.value" >
         { { env.viewValue } }
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout = "row" >
    <label fxFlex="1 6 60%"> Name</label>
    <md-input fxFlex = "3 1 40%" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name"
     formControlName="name">
    </md-input>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout = "row" >
    <label fxFlex="1 6 60%"> Cloud</label>
    <md-select fxFlex = "3 1 40%" placeholder="Choose Chain"
     formControlName="chaintype" (ngModelChange="")="toEnv($event)">
      <md-option* ngFor = "let env of cl"[value=""] = "env.value" >
        {{ env.viewValue }}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout = "row" >
    <label fxFlex="1 6 60%"> Enviroment</label>
    <md-select fxFlex = "3 1 40%" placeholder="Choose Environment"
      formControlName="selEnv">
      <md-option* ngFor = "let env of enviroment"[value=""] = "env.value" >
        {{ env.viewValue }}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </div>
  <div class="box-btn-dialog" [hidden=""]="ftUser">
    <button md-raised-button="" class="auto-btn-prime"
      disabled=""]="!custAppDetail.valid" type="submit">LAUNCH</button>
    <button md-raised-button="" class="auto-btn-gray" md-dialog-close="cancel"
     type="button">CANCEL</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

For the first row fxLayout="row" works but not for the rest of 4 rows, I would want the rest of the rows to be rendered as the first rows renders. I am using "@angular/core": "^2.4.3","@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.1",
And also the height of md-select is different from md-input; how the heights of ll the fields can be made same.

Comment: @AJT_82,@Pankaj Parkar,@Nehal please ur valuable inputs

Comment: @George Alexandria could you please help me with how to format the html tag

Comment: Did you read [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)?

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria I am not able to understand the formatting rules

Comment: What exactly did not you understand?

Comment: I have to leave 4 spaces for indentation but how to format the whole html code

Comment: You need to leave not less the 4 spaces for formatting, so you can try to edit your answer and look at the formatted html, where you find that code have 4, 8 etc spaces

Comment: You code has a lot wonky stuff like `* ngFor`, `md-raised-button=""`, `[hidden=""]="ftUser"`, `disabled=""]="!custAppDetail.valid"` !!!!!!!! But after cleaning up all that, I was able to recreate the view in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PMIcSOT1rkgkPQ4LeWuP?p=preview). I don't see any issues with the rows. If your problem still exists, use this plunker to recreate your issue, and share the link in your question for others.

Comment: Also, you can find the solution for fixing `md-select` and `md-input` in the css file of the plunker. Let me know if that resolves your problem.

Comment: @Nehal It worked thanks alot for quick help and insight , will get back with further queries

Comment: Ok, I'll put it as an answer then

Comment: @Nehal yeah sure:)

Comment: One more thing any insight the same thing I was trying to do earlier as well but was not working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, there's a lot of wrong code in your html like `* ngFor`, `md-raised-button=""`, `[hidden=""]="ftUser"`, `disabled=""]="!custAppDetail.valid"`. Once you clean up those things, the code seems to work fine.

html:

```
<p class="normal-gray-txt text-center">
  <b>
    Choose reference
    architecture
  </b>
</p>
<form fxLayout="column" >
  <div fxLayout = "row" class="row-height">
    <label fxFlex="1 6 60%"> Architecture file source</label>
    <md-select fxFlex = "3 1 40%" placeholder="abc">
      <md-option *ngFor = "let env of [1, 2, 3, 4]" >
        {{ env }}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout = "row" class="row-height">
    <label fxFlex="1 6 60%"> Architecture file</label>
    <md-select fxFlex = "3 1 40%" placeholder= "Choose file">    
      <md-option *ngFor = "let env of [1, 2, 3, 4]" >
        {{ env }}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout = "row" class="row-height">
    <label fxFlex="1 6 60%"> Name</label>
    <md-input fxFlex = "3 1 40%" placeholder="Enter Name">
    </md-input>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout = "row" class="row-height">
    <label fxFlex="1 6 60%"> Cloud</label>
    <md-select fxFlex = "3 1 40%" placeholder="Choose Chain">
      <md-option *ngFor = "let env of [1, 2, 3, 4]" >
        {{ env }}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout = "row" class="row-height">
    <label fxFlex="1 6 60%"> Enviroment</label>
    <md-select fxFlex = "3 1 40%" placeholder="Choose Environment">
      <md-option *ngFor = "let env of [1, 2, 3, 4]" >
        {{ env }}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </div>
  <div class="box-btn-dialog">
    <button md-raised-button class="auto-btn-prime">LAUNCH</button>
    <button md-raised-button class="auto-btn-gray">CANCEL</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/PMIcSOT1rkgkPQ4LeWuP?p=preview)

To fix the input row height issue, add these css in your component's stylesheet.

```
.row-height{
  min-height: 55px;
}

md-input{
  margin-top: -15px !important;
}
```

Comment: I have used it again and now it works , dont know why it was not working,thanks for the help :)